# Adding a page title and back button to fragments in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Ive pasted the code from my fragment and an image of the UI. How do I replace the App title with the title 'About' as well as adding a back arrow, so user can return to the previous screen.

````
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.milople.fajralarm.R;
import java.util.Objects;

public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView lbllink;
    View view;
    Context ctx;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ctx=getActivity();
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
        lbllink=view.findViewById(R.id.lbllink);
        lbllink.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://thehalallife.co.uk/"));
            startActivity(intent);
        });
        Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).setSubtitle("");
        return view;
    }

} ```

[screenshot of UI][2]

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ83X.png
````

Answer (score 1):

Activity to set CustomAppBar and Title for showing Title text and Every fragment to pass fragment title using AndroidViewModel to Actvity and set title with Appbar title when new fragment added or back press to finish any fragment

1.Pass every Fragment title to Activity using

```
viewModel.currentFragment("Cart");
```

2. Pass every Fragment title to Activity using

   ```
    public var pFrgment = MutableLiveData<String>()
    fun currentFragment(fragment: String) {
    pFrgment.value=fragment
    }
   ```

3.Activity to get Current Fragment title  and set with AppBar title

```
     viewModel.pFrgment.observe(this, Observer {
        pFrgment= it
        binding.btntitleBarProduct.text= pFrgment
    }
```

4. Activity onBackPress to pop fragment if needed

   ```
    override fun onBackPressed() {
    val count = supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    }
   ```

Comment: Can you be more specific with what needs to go where?

Comment: Every fragments load On Activity. So That Fragment to pass title and observe with Activity to set Title. When About Fragment load App title will show about fragment to pass data within Appbar title. That's it.

Comment: can you explain more what is  the desired behavior of your app and what are you trying to do with it..then it will be possible to help you...

Comment: First of all, what is your desire needs?Expain